# Mock the input() in the module body

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, input, pytest

I've read a lot of materials, but nothing helped. I tried to write some unit tests using `pytest` and faced the following problem: i can mock the `input()` inside the function i want to test (using `@mock.patch` or `monkeypatch.setattr` for `builtins.input`).

This is the code in my module:

```
def double():
    a = input()
    return int(a) * 2
```

And this is my test file:

```
# @mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value='13')
def testing(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda: "13")
    assert double() == 26
```

But when i have `input()` in the body of my module i get the error - *OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using -s*.

Example:

```
def double(a):
    return int(a) * 2

x = input()
```

I can fix this with adding `if __name__ == "__main__"` before `x = input()`, but i'm curious if i can solve this in any other way. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Code on module level will be executed on import, so `x = input()` will be executed before your test. Monkeypatching will thus come too late and can't avert the error. You can e.g. move the module import inside your test function, first `monkeypatch.setattr(...)`, then `from mymod import double`, then `assert double() == 26`, but it's a clumsy solution either. Best is to avoid executing code on module level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!